# angular 6, cordova, android, social vk

Tags: android, angular, cordova, vk-sdk

trying to use cordova-vk plugin to make social vk.com login work together with angular 6 project. 
getting error

> VkSdk is not defined

have added this before module, but didnt help:

```
declare var VkSdk:any;
```

also this:

```
let VkSdk:any;
```

looks like VkSdk not created inside flatform, but how to debug?
did someone solved social login for angular and cordova? 
normal oauth not working because of 'base domain error' :(

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether this helps.

declare const window: any;

Access the plugin using 'window.VkSdk'.

Comment: Seems like that plugin is very old. You can try whether this Social Sharing plugin helps .https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin